# Waiting for emitted function to be finished

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm in need to know if an emitted task has finished. To be sure, I use a prop and check for the change using a watcher:

```
const recursiveFuzzyFill = () => {
    let awaitme = new Promise((resolve) => {
        try {
            if (fuse.search(mappingData.value[loopIndex].label).length) {
                var refIndex = fuse.search(mappingData.value[loopIndex].label)[0].refIndex;
                mappingData.value[loopIndex].value = refIndex;

                emit("refreshMappingDataValues", attribute, data ? data.select_value : null, true);

                watch(() => props.changingMapping, (newval) => {
                        loopIndex++;
                        resolve();
                    }
                );
            } else {
                loopIndex++;
                resolve();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            loading.value = false;
            return;
        }
    });

    awaitme.then(() => {
        if (loopIndex === mappingData.value.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                loading.value = false;
                loopIndex = 0;
            }, 300);
            return;
        } else {
            recursiveFuzzyFill();
        }
    });
};
```

The method in the parent component does an ajax request and sets `props.changingMapping` either to `true` or `false` depending on its state.

Question is: Is this a proper way of doing it? Is it legit or common practice to use a watcher inside a method? I don't see a different way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state manager like vuex or pinia an event bus like mitt.

For example with vuex define a state `mapping` and an action `setAction`.
All actions return promises and can be used with async await.

So in your parent component you could dispatch the action to set the updated mapping and when the promise resolves emit an event through mitt and listen to this event in your child component.

Not sure if it is a bad way using the watcher in a method, but if it works it works.

Comment: I especially didn't want to use Vuex in this case cause there's no use for it except of this case. But thanks for the answer! I like the "if it works it works".

Comment: Yeah that would be quiet an overkill two use this design pattern for only this part.
Maybe only using the event bus might work but you have to make sure the parent is allset and done when it emits the event.

Comment: Yea, I know. That's why I needed to track whether the ajax call has finished or not.